# C++11: g++-4.7 internal compiler error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, g++

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

constexpr int N = 1000000;
constexpr int f(int x) { return x*2; }

typedef array<int, N> A;

template<int... i> struct F { static constexpr A f() { return A{{ ::f(i)... }}; } };

template<class A, class B> struct C {};
template<int... i, int... j> struct C<F<i...>, F<j...>> : F<i..., (sizeof...(i)+j)...>
{
        using T = F<i..., (sizeof...(i)+j)...>;
};

template<int n> struct S : C<typename S<n/2>::T, typename S<n-n/2>::T> {};
template<> struct S<1> : F<0> { using T = F<0>; };

constexpr auto X = S<N>::f();

int main()
{
        cout << X[3] << endl;
}
```

Produces an internal compiler error in GCC 4.7 in `-std=gnu++11` mode.

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++11 test.cpp
g++-4.7.real: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: On 4.7.1 I have `cc1plus: out of memory allocating 1048576 bytes after a total of 401997824 bytes`. Looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: I am on 4.7.2 and have 32GB of memory.  Either of these could explain difference.

Comment: Probably because 8 GB here but when decreasing the value of `N` it  then compiles correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that your program requires an unreasonable amount of memory (perhaps because of too many template expansions).

Using a recent `g++-trunk` :

```
gcc version 4.8.0 20121026 (experimental) [trunk revision 192860] (GCC)
```

with the following zsh limits:

```
   % limit          
   cputime         unlimited
   filesize        unlimited
   datasize        15000MB
   stacksize       8MB
   coredumpsize    400MB
   memoryuse       15000MB
   maxproc         128166
   descriptors     1024
   memorylocked    64kB
   addressspace    16000MB
   maxfilelocks    unlimited
   sigpending      128166
   msgqueue        819200
   nice            0
   rt_priority     0
   rt_time         unlimited
```

(this on Debian/Sid/AMD64 with i3770K intel processor & 16Gb RAM)

I am getting:

```
  % time g++-trunk -std=gnu++11 andrew.cc -o andrew
  virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
  g++-trunk -std=gnu++11 andrew.cc -o andrew :
  108.25s user 3.28s system 89% cpu 2:03.98 total
```

So it seems that template expansion requires so much memory that you program is not reasonable.

I'm not sure if this will be accepted as a GCC bug. The macro expansion for C++ templates is known to be Turing complete and you just hit the wall. And the GCC trunk does report a fatal, but understandable error.

The moral of the story might be to [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) appropriately (with limits compatible with your system and hardware), perhaps using `limit` zsh built-in or `ulimit` bash built-in.

Comment: I'm interested to know how exactly ~10^6 expansions can exhaust 32GB of memory.  The recursion depth is small, otherwise it would hit the 512 depth limit.  It works for N=10000 so it looks like it is using O(N^2) space somehow, but it should only be using O(NlogN) space.

Comment: The reason is simple: a compiler wants (and for most users should) to keep a lot of data in its internal representation. So the actual expansion happens on internal representations (Gcc Generic) which is more complex than what you imagine (e.g. because it remembers the source location position for every thing).

Comment: Remembering the source location should not be sufficient to explain an asymptotic growth in resource requirements.  For a constant explosion as big as this GCC would need approximately 32kb per instantiation, which is preposterous.

Comment: Then please contribute to GCC by submitting the relevant patch.

Comment: clang++ compiled this (after increasing -fconstexpr-steps) with no problem in about 1.5G of memory, in under 10 seconds. g++ grew to 15G and was killed after ~4min. (Yes, it still does this after all these years).

Answer (score 1):

An internal error means that you hit a compiler bug.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos: Yes; and please take time to report that bug on http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/