# Can a large number of warnings increase compilation time?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compilation, compiler-warnings

I have heard from someone that big projects with a large number of warnings in code builds significantly slower than ones with a small amount of warnings (of course, it is intended that the compiler's set to have high level warning-sensitivity).

Is there any reasonable explanation, or maybe anyone can share their experience about this topic?

Comment: Fix the warnings. Always. They are your friends.

Comment: Are you asking if changing the warning level changes the compile speed? Ie Will disabling warnings speed up compiling. Or whether code which generates a lot of warnings is inherently slower to compile?

Comment: "Or whether code which generates a lot of warnings is inherently slower to compile?" - this one

Comment: I hope is asking for the second one

Comment: It cannot be answered definitely. I can create non-warning code that is slow to compile and warning code that is fast to compile. However, in general, code with lots of warnings is more likely to be sloppy, and therefore more likely to be inefficient and wasteful (and probably buggy to boot).

Comment: The more warnings you have, the more stuff that needs to be printed, and the longer the compilation runs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. `gcc` for C or `g++` for C++) warnings do take a small amount of CPU time. Use e.g. `gcc -ftime-report` if you want a detailed report of compiler timing. Warning diagnostics do depend upon the optimization level.

But optimizations (especially at high level, like `-O2` or more) take much more time than warnings. Empirically, optimized compilation time is proportional to the compilation unit size and to the *square* of the size (e.g. in number of [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) instructions, or in lines of C code) of the biggest function. So if you have huge functions (e.g. some function of ten thousand lines in some generated C code) you may want to split them into smaller pieces.

<sup>In the early days of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a GCC plugin and GCC experimental branch -GPLv3+ licensed- implementing a DSL to extend [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), that I have developed and am still working on), it generated *huge* initialization functions in C (today it is less the case, the initialization is split in many C++ functions; see e.g. [gcc/melt/generated/warmelt-base.cc](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt/generated/warmelt-base.cc?view=co) from the MELT branch of GCC as an example). At that time, I plotted the compilation `-O2` time versus the length of that initialization function and measured the compilation time vs its length. You could also experiment with [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) code. Again, the square of biggest function length is an experimental measure, but might be explained by register allocation issues. Also, [J.Pitrat](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2013/11/my-view-on-artificial-intelligence/) also observed that huge generated C functions -by his interesting [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/04/caia-my-colleague/) system- are exhausting the compiler.</sup>

Also, warnings are output, and sometimes, the IDE or the terminal reading the compiler output may be slowed down if you have a lot of warnings.

Of course, as commented several times, *compiler warnings are your friends* (so *always* compile with e.g. `gcc -Wall`). So please **improve your code to get no warnings** at all. (In particular, initialize most of your local variables - I usually initialize all of them; since the compiler could optimize by removing some initializations if it can be proven that they are useless).

BTW, you could customize GCC with e.g. [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to add your own customized warnings (e.g. to check *some* coding rules conformance).

Also, in C++ with weird templates, you could write a few dozens of lines which take many hours to be compiled (or even crash the compiler because of lack of memory, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13103396/841108)).

NB. In 2019, GCC MELT is dead, its domain `gcc-melt.org` disappeared but the web pages are archived [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/).

Comment: `"Empirically, optimized compilation time is proportional to the compilation unit size and to the square of the size of the biggest function"` Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: MELT is something you created, is it part of the official gcc?

Comment: Is your observation about compilation time true for official gcc -O2, or your plugin only?

Comment: It is *empirically* observable in every version of GCC (with `-O2` for x86-64). Feel free e.g. to play with my `manydl.c` -which also generates C code of arbitrarily large length- to measure yourself.

Comment: How do you define size of the function? Assembly instructions?

Comment: In practice, they are roughly the same (lines of code in a given function is proportional to function machine size). But you could count Gimple instructions (with MELT!) if you want to be very serious.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. What is roughly the same?

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on what the warnings actually are.

For an example, if there are lots of "variable is unused" warnings and "condition in 'if' is always true/false" warnings, then that may mean there's a lot of unnecessary code that the compiler has to parse and then remove during optimisation.

For other warnings there may be other consequences. For example, consider a "variable is self initialising" warning caused by something like `int i = i;`. I'd imagine this could add a whole pile of complications/overhead (where the compiler attempts to determine if the variable is "live" or can be optimised out).

Answer (score 2):

This will likely depend extensively on the compiler, and how it is implemented.

That being said, there are two sure sources of slow-down:

1. Printing the warnings themselves is a non-trivial task, it requires extensive formatting, potentially accessing back the file, plus all those notes (macro expansion, template instantiation), and finally pushing that to an I/O device.
2. Emitting said warnings, with all those macro expansion and template instantiation data, might be non-trivial too. Furthermore, if collected first and only emitted at the end of the compilation process (instead of being streamed as they are produced), then the growing memory consumption will also slow you down (requiring more pages to be provided by the OS, ...)

In general, in terms of engineering, I do not expect compiler writers to worry much about the cost of emitting diagnostics; as long as it is a reasonable cost, there seems to be little incentive in optimizing a couple milli-seconds when a human intervention is going to be required anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Who cares if your build takes 10% longer due to the compiler printing tons of warnings?  The problem is the code you're being warned about, not the extra time it takes.  Besides, 10% is probably a huge overestimate for the overhead of printing even very large numbers of warnings.

Comment: I think that's a completely non-objective answer. Maybe it's not an "important" question, but don't deserve this treatment.

Comment: You'd be surprised how much time that printing can cost. Especially since the code is likely not optimized to print thousands of warnings. An O(N*N) algorithm can be reasonable there (e.g. in buffer allocation).

Comment: From a technical point of view it's interesting to know if "bad code" can slow down the compiler and how (not only with the 'print' overhead).