# Install Fails - R package Boom 0.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I'm unable to install Boom 0.9 on Ubuntu 18.04, Boom 0.8 installs without issue. However, we need 0.9 as a pre-req for CausalImpact.

```html
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:176: recipe for target 'Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2.o' failed
make[1]: *** [Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/fill_poisson_mixture_approximation_table_2.o] Error 4
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpKl6J7B/R.INSTALL90e7ca998b2/Boom/src'
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Boom'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Boom'

The downloaded source packages are in
 '/tmp/RtmpIk7UFT/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("Boom") : installation of one or more packages failed,
  probably 'Boom'
```

I've ensured that build-essential is up to date with the most current version available (and tried g++-8 as well).

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Its part of a docker build which is running in a teamcity build agent that has 25GB of RAM available (of 32 GB total).

Comment: Ah, never mind. I've had this issue before on systems with low memory, a la https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2473 , but guess that isn't it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think someone else in your org may have already contacted me about this.  We are mid-flight debugging.

Boom is a large package and can time out when building.  The first thing to check is that you are able to build with multiple cores (i.e. you can pass the -j x flag to make).

As a diagnostic you can try building the package without involving R.  Clone https://github.com/steve-the-bayesian/BOOM and build with either bazel (up to date) or make (not too far out of date).  If this build succeeds then compare flags passed to the R build vs the native build.

To better understand where R is failing, download the Boom package from CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Boom_0.9.1.tar.gz and try the following from the command line
R CMD CHECK Boom_0.9.1.tar.gz

This will probably fail, but it will generate a directory called Boom.Rcheck, which contains a file 00install.out containing all the compiler output.

It is suspicious that the build above fails on the poisson_mixture_approximation_table, which is a large file that might be overflowing your stack.  Or that might be a coincidence.

Comment: It did end up being memory related, there were a couple things I did to work around it.
1) I increased the docker memory limit to 8g on my laptop so that I could just do a one off install of Boom when running it locally (it had been 2g). This helped for testing, but not a fix for the real issue.
2) On the TeamCity agent there was 30g+ available to docker but the build would still fail (this seems odd to me still). To work around this, I modified the docker file to install Boom by itself in a separate command first, then install the other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_Boom.html

The check page says 'GNU make' is a undeclared SystemRequirement.

> Version: 0.9.1 
>   Check: for GNU extensions in Makefiles 
>   Result: NOTE 
>       GNU make is a SystemRequirements.

Since your installation process also seems to fail at make[1] it might make sense to check if GNU make is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, GNU make is already installed.

 # make --version
 GNU Make 4.1
 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: What a pity, that would have been a easy solution :-)

Comment: What you could do is download the old source code of the 0.8 version of the package ( https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Boom/ )  and compare for changes ... maybe this can give an indication. A little bit unfortunate that they don't have a changelog or a Github repo for the package.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of the Boom package from source (also during the Docker build) can fail for several reasons:

- low memory pro core
- low stack size
- timeout of the build process (possible)

We are currently using the following setup for Docker:

- core: 4
- memory: 8GB

We can use the following command to set the stack size to 16MB before starting the installation:

Docker:

```
RUN ulimit -s 16384 \
    && R -e 'install.packages("Boom");'
```

Linux:

```sh
ulimit -s 16384 \
    && R -e 'install.packages("Boom");'
```

Note: The stack size is an operating system-related configuration and can vary depending on the host operating system used.

Note: The command to install the boom package may be different for your application. We use for example packrat.

Similar issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104232/5770014)